# How to prevent mail app from marking e-mails from VIP as spam

Tags: macos, mail.app

I set someone's e-mail address as VIP, but lately his e-mails end up in the junk folder. Is there any way in the mail app to prevent a certain address's e-mails to be marked as junk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure this person is in your Contacts, including the email address you want to mark as not being spam.  This is important because Mail checks there when determining what's spam.

Then, go to the Mail → Preferences, ‘Junk Mail’ tab, and make sure the following options are checked:

- Enable Junk Mail Filtering
- Choose ‘Mark as junk mail, but leave it in my Inbox’
- The Following Types of Messages are exempt from Junk Mail Filtering:

  - Sender of message is in my Contacts
  - Sender of message is in my Previous Recipients
  - Message is addressed using my full name
  - Also select Trust junk mail headers in messages

After you do all this, Mail might still put some email in Spam/Junk.  Just right-click on the email and select ‘Not junk mail’.  It's not perfect but eventually it should learn.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this without adding the sender to my contacts? I've been continuously marking junk mail as not junk in an attempt to "train" the app (but I'm not sure if that's a thing).

Comment: @DecadeMoon I'm not aware of any other way.