# How to prevent Mail.app from marking legit mails as junk

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, high-sierra

First of all, I've seen [How to prevent mail app from marking e-mails from VIP as spam](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236372/how-to-prevent-mail-app-from-marking-e-mails-from-vip-as-spam) and did the steps.

For some reason, Mail.app (macOS 10.13.2) thinks perfectly legit mails are junk:

[image]

These are mails that I voluntarily opted in to receive.

- I've tried "Move to Inbox" on some, but it doesn't help new ones received as junk.
- The answer at the above link says "right click the mail and select 'Not Junk'", there is no such option.
- I've set my junk filtering as follows:
  [image]
- I've added the sender to my contacts, I can confirm that it's added with its email address.
- I've also tried replacing the "From does not contain" field in the screenshot above with the actual email address of the sender instead of its name.
- I've added the sender to VIP.

After all these, these mails (which for me are important to be notified immediately upon receiving) are still being marked as junk.

Am I missing something obvious, or Mail.app is seriously flawed? I understand mails related to trading etc might initially marked as junk, but is it *that hard* to mark legit e-mails as not junk?

*UPDATE:* Here are the full headers, if it helps:

```
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Pcl: ⁨2⁩
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Cfa-Test: ⁨BCL:4;PCL:0;RULEID:(444111537)(1160499008)(595095)(82015058);SRVR:BN3NAM04HT100;BCL:4;PCL:0;RULEID:(100000803101)(100110400095);SRVR:BN3NAM04HT100;⁩
X-Eoptenantattributedmessage: ⁨84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0⁩
X-Incomingheadercount: ⁨11⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Crosstenant-Originalarrivaltime: ⁨04 Jan 2018 02:41:03.9670 (UTC)⁩
X-Originatororg: ⁨outlook.com⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Transport-Crosstenantheadersstamped: ⁨BN3NAM04HT100⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Authas: ⁨Anonymous⁩
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: ⁨EFV:NLI;SFV:NSPM;SFS:(98901004);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:1;SRVR:BN3NAM04HT100;H:a11-70.smtp-out.amazonses.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:;⁩
X-Message-Info: ⁨qoGN4b5S4yrBSqyABj5gSnTTTq97NQC/i4RS6t59hHxEwxi1cumMMVlWua+Q7NxcRifrmK7cHhBKce9czxxomp/oGmIxvlj7FR00kHsUwmCdQTEsjUneVhdg/1fUFqlPAcdoE08l4dC3uCIHUAvQtfqR1wGxoPyMH2tqHruLoalzORZXxL1FPvEAiMJyToJPHvIORWc0lx5AWrBuVySmyQ==⁩
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-Test: ⁨UriScan:;⁩
X-Sid-Result: ⁨NONE⁩
Authentication-Results: ⁨spf=pass (sender IP is 54.240.11.70) smtp.mailfrom=amazonses.com; canpoyrazoglu.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=amazonses.com;canpoyrazoglu.com; dmarc=none action=none header.from=tradingview.com;⁩
X-Sender-Ip: ⁨54.240.11.70⁩
Return-Path: ⁨01000160bf0b17ff-6223938a-2eff-42bf-8670-fd8ab7a9cc89-000000@amazonses.com⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Crosstenant-Fromentityheader: ⁨Internet⁩
Spamdiagnosticoutput: ⁨1:5⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Crosstenant-Id: ⁨84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa⁩
X-Ses-Outgoing: ⁨2018.01.04-54.240.11.70⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: ⁨f0979bbd-f76e-499f-058c-08d5531c9964⁩
Spamdiagnosticmetadata: ⁨Default:4⁩
Original-Message-Id: ⁨<151503332444.123150.11756710792440281369@prod-frontend-web-4.prod>⁩
X-Ms-Publictraffictype: ⁨Email⁩
X-Sid-Pra: ⁨NOREPLY@TRADINGVIEW.COM⁩
X-Microsoft-Antispam: ⁨BCL:4;PCL:0;RULEID:(5000109)(4604075)(4605076)(610169)(8291501071);SRVR:BN3NAM04HT100;⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Eopdirect: ⁨true⁩
⁨<01000160bf0b17ff-6223938a-2eff-42bf-8670-fd8ab7a9cc89-000000@email.amazonses.com>⁩
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info: ⁨MpfJYXfy6pEFkExnTKDeS7T09SndviLzrrFcCyNMBRyuvWShR19yeMxKrJgA0drlrnNvVWez3GJGoe8AzuEjKzt5M0dZpX7/3PVY5d4hTNw8bTrYQySAdkQtNQmJ10lDtYi9NhX9xictZ4XGkBppfQ==⁩
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Message-Info: ⁨aCTmxtvkKUrTg6ZyTJfEQj7F8gM+ah24L34Eebeca6Ry1fsVzo/60z5JxWpYuVYUSN/WfTALFsttV1IB6Hx1xkCRuDwxqabKMry/R2k03k0QApYvJ5WXUqJZjdui8A9eQXgliLeg2GHyXrSI6wdn5nUKa30ook2P/23wZssIpyyFELPfmrd73xqYuxTfenlQRs1LA8DHAJ3avjZkLEXqKGBQDpURS8f5dr2A0tQD1vqnhsRtS4EIesuIXjSZg5GYHxFy/CO0gdj0GYX7I3gQ3EwRxRSfcbt6KoTWIBLwsXQ=⁩
Mime-Version: ⁨1.0⁩
X-Message-Delivery: ⁨Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0xO1NDTD02⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Processed-By-Bccfoldering: ⁨15.20.0386.006⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Authsource: ⁨BN3NAM04FT020.eop-NAM04.prod.protection.outlook.com⁩
X-Ms-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: ⁨f0979bbd-f76e-499f-058c-08d5531c9964⁩
Received: ⁨from BN3NAM04HT100.eop-NAM04.prod.protection.outlook.com (10.174.66.32) by BN6PR01MB2388.prod.exchangelabs.com with HTTPS via BN3PR03CA0114.NAMPRD03.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Thu, 4 Jan 2018 02:41:05 +0000⁩
Received: ⁨from BN3NAM04FT020.eop-NAM04.prod.protection.outlook.com (10.152.92.57) by BN3NAM04HT100.eop-NAM04.prod.protection.outlook.com (10.152.92.251) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384_P384) id 15.20.302.6; Thu, 4 Jan 2018 02:41:03 +0000⁩
Received: ⁨from a11-70.smtp-out.amazonses.com (54.240.11.70) by BN3NAM04FT020.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.92.167) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_0, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA_P384) id 15.20.345.12 via Frontend Transport; Thu, 4 Jan 2018 02:41:03 +0000⁩
X-Eopattributedmessage: ⁨0⁩
Content-Type: ⁨multipart/alternative; boundary="===============6410045645009015316=="⁩
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery: ⁨abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;psp:1;auth:0;dest:J;ENG:(400001000128)(400125000095)(5062000261)(5061607266)(5061608174)(4900095)(4920089)(6370004)(4950112)(4990090)(9140004);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;⁩
X-Ms-Traffictypediagnostic: ⁨BN3NAM04HT100:⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Scl: ⁨1⁩
Received-Spf: ⁨Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of amazonses.com designates 54.240.11.70 as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=54.240.11.70; helo=a11-70.smtp-out.amazonses.com;⁩
Feedback-Id: ⁨1.us-east-1.dJX2xx0zsf93o2zkSlILUU/8EdBfridsykCSgjgyirk=:AmazonSES⁩
X-Incomingtopheadermarker: ⁨OriginalChecksum:DFE25DF6E1176832B58B9701057EA5C6C6BEB77E7702278F4B1F63486777F8C8;UpperCasedChecksum:D85F5608BA49F2A0DD0CCED36F471162B17C499B607A46952B950534BFBABFA6;SizeAsReceived:1036;Count:11⁩
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: ⁨1;BN3NAM04FT020;1:OKFPkRT6CZMAj/vPT5dJ9Fp9U4L/0ZaC8CVLUVQLwsBjHwYVrIFm+SVfgoPMgIY/FVxc+bl8xUsuAMIhcKmcF/s0ogyf8bt63RdhJRU+fJznZTD6OWkmYiD72Y0ZwDlb⁩
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: ⁨1;BN3NAM04HT100;3:eE/BfbIWRWNiMkP3G4BlDNhg6TI3xRLLjglOB6T5p9xA4zNVbKfWX+GuHJXIgpeFolpUPUrLZ2U8UYS2O3KTq+Y37P8eUTcppLWM4YiaqBGiBjBPYyPaBU53y8Hf2n11K3j1ugJ5ol1Irn6gnlAtEqsQiFGau/R2uIXOZI4NGwTELOYU+lg4jIO0WkX8C1f7+Dk1HSZ6FVD+XcxZN2ebjxtfpImA/Anr7A7EVJRh7WdBmRiT4yCYuv3frURVVw30C3CfBBlpz9Rz+A0foQm79Y6rHBzubDLP0BSYk98qDYF2hlLOU5a3b+bR3BE1gyad;25:k3ldz8nVnIcCOieYVtFa2mTze4KZYF+SVLsf+knsrtxN5uoXLeqLRIOEXio30ZOkO8ssJbWTf02zGfE96ESLZ41l7028aStZdQO+ADQfY6zopzx7uMSx0YRiYkmHMHQvrWCZvZ5GneOr4hFJBP2KN5UC/2U/xLIBw1Dmw/oApL+/iFSZ49Hd9xeoKs1ea1st2T58yGPdHO/yA3sOIOfGBF2Od4JFKP18cNpUzyCuVf52zoZ8ShwMkDf5oIFi7oGkKWvgFNkFuGysMy41/T0Bb7l727FLcnfZQ2mQG1fEoFH49w+TymEYdIDQ88oRvdIRx5rKwIK3cMlMjzeZmeV3LA==;31:AWNj7tdQtGmZZ5uePsTHv4O797BRsim8BgZrUDBpYMMANZ8YZTAsx2T8UtBCFtFVzr4EUIA6a+JqXX3h4NnHA3EAI9aXKR3TCja8QnLemWXbk+bgS+OWUbm7o2zXqy0bm9E43ixOXyD/fqdwJLTO/PBlxtgXFsDK7v2I+5OB7M1y/dF9dxMG755zCMPFC24Omt6FJZFKudU66uEq8Uc1NYDwWs30sejJG89u4DT4QKo=⁩
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: ⁨1;BN3NAM04HT100;4:fMd2rA1xsslf4iWgA5v151mPvkuBIip2h/g7q+RECZjMQ6urU+Di3mDU14vbqPAyY0ZVxa9OrbI3HU4dNZCcZ691X76kFpARlEztMAXu1suqqCD5vODSnjQikTDE1f93FMIRBP0f+CQITHgbQXFtonQ0/sbjcooZWNegsS6ldwTavO7qeQ3DAIz/h03+gbSONrrJOI6EM0mx6AcRqfM59+w5BfKW1+euDPaxbmPs30IHkzYHcoCbLLl1rYXszMs15Zdz1amum47HPr3oj3XxAA==;23:kqiqI0/ubUREln85iJs8CHGkMDNFORz23KjxdPlxbyfDP2N2tTY7h4PxzWTgFM6b4V74NvqUWFlWWK8ZASX6/zvqI2/lWv0XOJg3e+hRPpOGNP/+FfctthfbBfDFoJvbCUTY0ijwEd3QLFzNuU9Vuw1vWXzc4uNA/EMdIElDUOQ=;6:7JHKQSgkJ+mtbfIXk9izrz+Jl7ziz2gHCyH9uyt7QyMGTMPJDeCDujakrxhqpIztTooRJ3pTfS78Vh1AET7WmoyVvoewxYMb85xTTptBvA39Hm99+xwscJCwLht2IJhXSVNWT+iMfZwr1NcpmOqIhPNYg4QiKhIq7gO7DoJccOfxGRSSeFErZRQuhP9LojFguOXbxCuHEnPKTyoi5mZl5CgVtrhQgzd7fOCKtMndndqL8oo4Dp6tJrlzq2EulopShwtcF+CuRCBf0shv8wz4Tm9Oo2K//bqgj3ZlNvWH9p/N+L4E/k2h3Wax4Y7S0QZyQYwdVRAW8e/1aCNa3VnUSPs0DfO04FaNaVTVI4lNsns=⁩
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: ⁨1;BN3NAM04HT100;5:T9breMhld1jNrZw7hEKOvF6JtcxhiljNMvcoGUrs3YNxTScrARepXHRtbANQBjZg0KMqbde8nsWA0DP2hqubUp7vrh/SAFkvsk1uP0Y4Ndmzce3uekrdEJ5h9hoktoX24Rk3k4KUJTaodvHfILCyzi5JvFKr856UIyehrOwdfPY=;24:ispqaeIcozTvpGZamGPMYdKVObIJAt2teObNvGisEVjtkR64fhfsNDR2dctPMyWtR0l37qJDYLNhdMcNuoKEXQzgMnGqz+NmZ6efRIXMYUE=;7:k/JxjxAW/8+0gD55bbuIYUt55KNT8d2UHlDdDW+yTV1p2B7zJx6rS2xBxg//a5Z1B4WRRrrev8Os+5qEgBGMbyeWpigx+W+YHvLmYa3590HI2dYe1q3r0YnQnkfkHnggdRJiPJQbi9n77RJpDyCbsekqAN+wvjOP+J4ZUzHEzHEQ4h16OzACou/fjJ/ai6R9e1P1NC+lWZnoJVJSQRlsN6xTPB9BL0uPWE4ePpY5Yx5tYHlzsjZpI5iokSzbvTSK⁩
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: ⁨1;BN6PR01MB2388;27:NFVYvZLubK1eiUzhqKbDPI2BHQwZIEF+4Dp1/MOWCvNKuEVuJK4K1MV/epNp28gaDawaQjd6yax7GYMVxlVmaqOCHHkvA98AYgohOadXhQUKKS65lph0gNgv5+DgTawK⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Organization-Messagedirectionality: ⁨Incoming⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Crosstenant-Network-Message-Id: ⁨f0979bbd-f76e-499f-058c-08d5531c9964⁩
X-Ms-Exchange-Transport-Endtoendlatency: ⁨00:00:01.2379178⁩
Dkim-Signature: ⁨v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple; s=224i4yxa5dv7c2xz3womw6peuasteono; d=amazonses.com; t=1515033663; h=Content-Type:MIME-Version:Subject:From:To:Date:Message-ID:Feedback-ID; bh=A5frUla2xQIWcmPgFCa09qFcKlW9T1Vi3aAWaxTA9Bk=; b=JK82+uJKpLNAqcZocvo2Qq9C86ThOUsPdGkmv6kqA+9QGZ1M+PWV3tr1sozAgP9c s5+CRJajjM4ZCLsMV4d5HJL91pWktTtEtEesOiyyUuRGcfeivII4LpsSZu38aPThjDv wPMk8Z9NI7R1ssaXNv1vV6SR4ddenjG4rXCbFZRY=⁩
```

Comment: Use the [Show Full Email Headers](http://osxdaily.com/2016/04/06/show-long-email-header-mac-mail-osx/) command and copy/paste the contents into your question. Perhaps there is something there triggering Mail to choke and think its SPAM.

Comment: @IconDaemon I've added the headers. but even then, shouldn't my settings clearly override spam detecting mechanism even if Mail.app thinks mail is 100% scam?

Comment: Have you tried to access this account over a web interface to see if they’re showing up in a SPAM folder there?

Comment: @IconDaemon yep, I've now added an exception for the sender. let's see how the next mail processes.

Comment: Can confirm "Not junk" is no longer present, only move to inbox.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I feel like the "not junk" button would help; why did they take that away? I don't really want to add all these email addresses to my contacts because they aren't really my friends and I don't want my contact list getting cluttered. I do want the emails, though.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I can't see from what you posted is the actual email address in the "From" field, so I'm wondering if that might be part of the problem. Looking at my rules, I see that when I'm using a "From" targeted rule I always use the actual email address, or partial email address, like "@importantdomain.com."

My suggestion would be to change your last line to a subject rule, so "Subject does not contain TradingView." If that makes the rule work, then there definitely is a problem with the email address in your contact you created for this sender.

And not strictly speaking an answer, but I would leave the spam rule for strictly finding spam and then have a separate, higher rule that would look for the "TradingView" emails, sort or flag them, then under "Perform the following actions:" choose "Stop evaluating rules." That should find the TradingView emails, do what you want with them, then perform no more rule actions on them. A little bit of a different philosophy, but it has worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

There are several ways you can prevent Mail from incorrectly marking legitimate messages as junk.

Tell Mail that a message is legitimate by marking it as not junk. Click Not Junk in the banner of the message; or select the message, then click the Not Junk button  in the Mail toolbar (or use the Touch Bar).

Add the sender to the Contacts app. For more information, see Use events, contacts, and other items found in emails.

Review your junk mail settings in the Junk Mail pane of Mail preferences, as well as any rules you might have created to handle junk mail, and make changes as necessary. - Apple Site https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/if-junk-mail-filters-arent-working-mlhlp1145/mac

Comment: The original question already included all these steps and they didn't work.  Why are you reposting the same steps as an answer to the question?

Comment: The "Not Junk" button doesn't exist anymore